# Find Closest date range by providing 2 dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by

I'm preparing a SQL report with following tables (Training and Resources):

```
Trainings
- Id
- Name
- StartDate
- EndDate
```

And

```
Resource
- Id
- FullName
- JoinedOn
- TerminatedOn
```

What I need is to get the Resources who are there during Training period. example, I'll pass Training **start** and **end** dates and based on these dates I need to extract closest resource:

```
Training Start Date: 01-08-2017
Training End Date: 04-08-2017
```

Resources

```
Emp1 (01-05-2016 and 30-09-2017)
Emp2 (01-03-2016 and 30-04-2017)
Emp3 (01-02-2016 and 30-09-2017)
Emp4 (01-08-2017 and 30-04-2018) -- This is the Closest match
Emp5 (01-09-2016 and 30-01-2017)
Emp6 (01-11-2016 and 30-02-2017)
```

Even though other date ranges also hold these dates but **01-08-2016** and **30-04-2017** is the closest one.

Please help me in achieving this. I tried the following:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 R.FullName
FROM    [Resource] R
WHERE   (
            (YEAR('01-08-2017') = YEAR(JoinedOn) AND Month('01-08-2017') = Month(JoinedOn) )
            OR 
            (YEAR('04-08-2017') = YEAR(TerminatedOn) AND Month('04-08-2017') = Month(TerminatedOn))
        )
ORDER BY TerminatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for.

```
declare @resource table 
(name varchar(50), joinedon date, terminatedon date)

insert @resource 
select 'e1', '2016-5-1', '2017-9-30' union 
select 'e2', '2016-3-1', '2017-4-30' union 
select 'e3', '2016-2-1', '2017-9-30' union 
select 'e4', '2017-8-1', '2018-4-30' union 
select 'e5', '2016-9-1', '2017-1-30' union 
select 'e6', '2016-11-1', '2017-2-28'

declare @start date= '2017-8-1', @end date = '2017-8-4'

select top 1 *
from @resource r
where joinedon<=@start and terminatedon>=@end
order by datediff(d, @end, terminatedon)+   datediff(d, joinedon, @start)
```